# Equivalence definition to semidirect product in the operated context

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebras, semigroups, semidirect-product

An operated semigroup (or a semigroup with an operator) is a semigroup $U$ together with an operator $\alpha : U \to U$ that is called the distinguished operator on $U$. Is there any definition equivalent to **semidirect product** in this context?

Comment: What is the definition of an operator? Could it be any map from $U$ to $U$?

Comment: In the context of algebras, differential Lie algebras, which we have a Lie algebras with a differential operator is an example.